Different ways to find isothermal coordinates
Say we have a toroidal surface parameterized by coordinates $\theta,\zeta$ and with isothermal coordinates $u,v$:

If the induced metric is a (nonconstant) multiple of the flat metric,  then the immersion is said to be conformal,  or isothermal, or in conformal coordinates, i.e. $ ‖r_u‖ = ‖r_v‖ $ and $〈r_u,r_v〉= 0 $ at every point.

Instead of finding a parametrization with coordinates $u,v$ such that $ ‖r_u‖ = ‖r_v‖ $ and $〈r_u,r_v〉= 0 $ to define the conformal parameterization, would it be enough to simply find solutions to the Laplace-Beltrami Equation $\nabla^2_s u = \nabla^2_s v = 0$?
The operator $\nabla^2_s$ could be defined directly with the coordinates $\theta, \zeta$ so it seems easier to me to find $u,v$ this way (using numerical methods).
